# How to fix bash errors in /etc/profile?

Tags: bash, postgresql

When i start my Postgresql it takes an while and i get this strange error message and i think like this file is corrupt?

```
[tis jan 28 20:03:56] Jonathan@Whats next?:~$ sudo systemctl start postgresql

[sudo] password for jonteyh: 
[tis jan 28 20:04:25] Jonathan@Whats next?:~$ sudo -u postgres -i

ö

-bash: /etc/profile: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

-bash: /etc/profile: line 14:

-Strange characters


-bash-5.0$ ö


-bash: ö: command not found


-bash-5.0$ psql


psql (11.5 (Ubuntu 11.5-1))


Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

How can i fix this error below?

```
-bash: /etc/profile: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

-bash: /etc/profile: line 14:
```

And when i do cat /etc/profile: I get this strange characters in terminal like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow, your `/etc/profile` file has been modified to be just a straight executable.  This could be due to user error or because of someone trying to maliciously hijack your system by executing programs whenever you connect or startup.

I'd replace your `/etc/profile` with something like this (this is the unaltered `/etc/profile` file from my 18.04 machine and is **identical** to the `/etc/profile` in 19.10):

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

I'd also suggest taking your existing /etc/profile that is an executable now and removing it after submitting it to VirusTotal for analysis to see if it's actually a recognized malware or something.